# mapping an array not returning value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array I'm trying to map values from, but it isn't returning what I need to continue with my project.

The codeblock in question is:

```
<select
    className={"clubsList"}
    defaultValue={"allClubs"}
    onChange={this.handleClubChange}>
    <option key={"allClubs"} value={"allClubs"}>All Clubs</option>
    {LEAGUE_IDS_NAMES.forEach(league => {
        if (league.id == this.props.fantasyLeagueId) {
            league.clubs.map(club => {
                console.log('club:', club.name);
                return <option key={club.name} value={club.name}>{club.name}</option>;
            });
        }
    })}
</select>
```

What this is intended to do is display a list of club names.  `LEAGUE_IDS_NAMES` is an imported file that is an array of objects.  These objects are soccer leagues, and one of the keys of each league is `clubs`, which in turn is an array of objects like this:

```
clubs: [
    {name: 'Club Name1'},
    {name: 'Club Name2'},
    ...
]
```

I'm using React/Redux to keep a league id in state and then am using that to compare against each league object in the array, checking the id of each.  If it matches, it is supposed to give me the return statement.  I know that I am accessing the club names properly as the console.log is correctly giving me club names for the league id in state.  What it's not doing is giving me the `<option>` part of it all.

To experiment, I threw a `return` in front of the `league.clubs.name` line, but still nothing.  The only thing I ever see for this `<select>` is the "All Clubs" `<option>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you can’t yield anything from [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Given its only clubs from a specific league you can filter the league and then map the clubs e.g.

```
const league = LEAGUE_IDS_NAMES.find(l => l.id === this.props.fantasyLeagueId);
return league && league.clubs.map(l => <option key={c.name} value={c.name}>{c.name}</option>)
```

Since you're following the Redux pattern, you can move the the filtering into a selector.

Comment: decent answer but I think your `find` should be a `filter`

Comment: @Kevin nah was deliberately `find` as it’s a specific league and not a list of leagues, just misuse of of `map` after, updated though.

Comment: This was it!  Thanks!  I wracked my brain for a little over a day on this one.